# Sublime Text Language (JavaScript (Rails)) Embedded Ruby in String

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, syntax, sublimetext

My .js.erb file looks like this:

```
console.log("<%= escape_javascript render("users/list") %>");
```

The problem here is that the whole embedded Ruby part is interpreted as a JavaScript String (no Syntax Highlighting inside) which I want to avoid. I have not found any solution to this. I have tried looking into the `.tmLanguage` file but all in vain.

Any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, idea to get the Ruby part out of the quotes.

```
 console.log(<%='"'.html_safe +  escape_javascript( render("users/list") ) + '"'.html_safe %>);
```

Comment: While this might be a workaround, I am looking for an answer on *how* to integrate the correct syntax highlighting. (most hopefully based on `tmLanguage` / Sublime implementation thereof). There are some things that I've run across which seem to be a bug in Sublime's `tmLanguage` or scope selector implementation and I'm looking for an informative answer.